# Posting Object Data from Console App to Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, console-application

I am creating a console app in .Net Core that gets data from a Web API, updates that data and does a Put to update the Web API data. I am running into an issue where I am losing my data at the HttpRequestBuilder when sending it to HttpContent and the Web API is not getting updated but I get a 200 returned. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    var requestUri = $"{baseUri}transactions/{transaction.ID}";
    return await HttpRequestFactory.Put(requestUri, transaction);
}
```

JsonContent:

```
public JsonContent(object value, string mediaType)
        :base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), Encoding.UTF8, mediaType)
{
}
```

HttpRequestFactory:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string requestUri, object value)
{
    var builder = new HttpRequestBuilder()
        .AddMethod(HttpMethod.Put)
        .AddRequestUri(requestUri)
        .AddContent(new JsonContent(value, "application/json"));

    return await builder.SendAsync();
}
```

HttpRequestBuilder:

```
 public HttpRequestBuilder AddContent(HttpContent content)
{
    this.content = content;
    return this;
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync()
{
    // Check required arguments
    EnsureArguments();

    // Setup request
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = this.method,
        RequestUri = new Uri(this.requestUri)
    };

    if (this.content != null)
        request.Content = this.content;

    request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.acceptHeader))
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(this.acceptHeader));

    // Setup client
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = this.timeout;

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Please do not confuse ASP.NET Core with .NET Core. Those are different products.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `JsonContent` class is doing the correct thing. We are missing the full class definition so I can only guess:

When you call it in the `Put` method it is returning an object to `.AddContent` but that is probably not getting serialized as the content string.

Change your `Put` method to call the `JsonConvert` method directly.

HttpRequestFactory:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string requestUri, object value)
{
    var builder = new HttpRequestBuilder()
        .AddMethod(HttpMethod.Put)
        .AddRequestUri(requestUri)
        .AddContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    return await builder.SendAsync();
}
```

If you do want to use your `JsonContent` class then you might be better with a static method to do the conversion rather than a class hierarchy?